# .NET 6 Why does fail to intercept the response body in middleware when a request is canceled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

I wrote a middleware in .NET 6 Web API to handle some response body processing, but I noticed that if the request is canceled before I finish processing inside, I will receive an empty response body in the middleware.

Later, I attempted to move this processing to an action filter, and I found that even if the request is canceled, I can still successfully obtain the response body.

I'm curious why the response body cannot be intercepted by the middleware after the request is canceled?

This is my middleware:

```
public class CustomResponseMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public CustomResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var originalBodyStream = httpContext.Response.Body;
        await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        httpContext.Response.Body = memoryStream;

        await _next(httpContext);

        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // The responseBody will be as empty string ("")
        var responseBody = await new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEndAsync(); 
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //Do some processing on the response body here

        httpContext.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
        await httpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's related to the [execution order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#how-filters-work)?

Comment: @TinyWang  I currently have the same suspicion, but I cannot find microsoft explanation on how they actually handle the response behind the scenes when a request is canceled.